# Trying to open external link injected from javascript with InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I have dealt before with opening external links using InAppBrowser. Now, I am facing a new problem. I have this JS code:

```
var randIndex = getRandomInt(0, bannersCollection.length - 1);
$scope.imgTitle = bannersCollection[randIndex].logo;
$scope.logoURL = bannersCollection[randIndex].url;
```

It provides the scope with a new logo and a url associated to that logo so I want to be able to click on the logo and navigate to that URL.

I do this with the HTML code:

```
<div ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
    <div class="card" ng-controller="cycleImagesCtrl">
        <a href={{logoURL}}>
            <div class="item item-body" style="margin-bottom: -7px;padding: 0px">
            <img src={{imgTitle}} width="100%" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Basically, each three cards I add a new one consisting of a banner and an associated URL.

Before, I could do links to work using this filter:

```
appFeria2016.filter('hrefToJS', function ($sce, $sanitize) {
return function (text) {
    var regex = /href="([\S]+)"/g;
    var newString = $sanitize(text).replace(regex, "onClick=\"window.open('$1', '_system', 'location=yes')\"");
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(newString);
}
```

});

But I have not managed to include the filter on this ... and it does not work. Any hints on this one?.

EDIT: URLS are stored like this:

```
{ logo: "img/bricomart-banner.png", url: "http://www.bricomart.com" },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand clearly what it is you want. Do you want to get the html contents of another website to read it as string? Do you want to open the website in a different webview (InAppBrowser does that for you)?

Comment: No, I have some JavaScript objects and one of its member is a URL. I wanted HTML to get that URL so it can be open outside my App. InApp allows to open outside the App but you need to pass the URL to a specific format so it can be parsed correctly. As href needs a "-surrounded string, it cannot be injected properly. I think I have found a way to go but I am still doing some tested

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ionic why you don't use [this plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/). All you have to do is this:

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://ngcordova.com', '_blank', options)
  .then(function(event) {
    // success
  })
  .catch(function(event) {
    // error
  });


$cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
```

And then handle the events:

```
'$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart'
'$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop'
'$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror'
'$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit'
```

Keep in ind to add ngcordova in your dependencies.

Comment: Well, I am already using that plugin but cannot manage it to work so that the url is loaded TO HTML and then processed correctly on a click event. So I don't know how to correctly inject the URL string and process the with the plugin to open it.

Comment: It seems to be complaining about the string format. I will rewrite my code to pass the whole object and see how it goes..